# Why is the body tag a stacking context, depending on the background color of the html tag

Tags: html, css, stacking-context

Every HTML page has a stacking context at the root element (`html`tag).

In the following example the `html` tag is the (only) stacking context

```css
html {
background-color: gray;
}
body {
background: #222;
color: white;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
}
.box:before {
content: "";
background-color: tomato;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
inset: 0;
margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The pseudo element (tomato color) is drawn behind the body background (#222) because it has a `z-index` < 0

If we remove the `html` tag background color:

```css
body {
background: #222;
color: white;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
}
.box:before {
content: "";
background-color: tomato;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
inset: 0;
margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Now the pseudo element (tomato color) is drawn after the body background (#222). That means that the `body` tag now creates a stacking context.

There are a [few rules that determine if an element creates a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). None of the rules explain why the `body` tag is now the root of a stacking context.

A [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109258/why-doesnt-the-z-index-style-apply-to-the-body-element) explains, from the specs, that the canvas uses the `body` background color/image if the `html` tag has none. This is possibly to match the early days of HTML when this [info was set with the `bgcolor` and `background` attributes of the `body` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37342517/9938317).

The question is: which part of the CSS specification is the reason of the `body` tag creating a stacking context depended on the html background color?

Comment: It seem more about whether or not the background color is fully transparent or not.

Comment: It seems like your research has taken you to all the right references, you've just not fully understood their implications. The body element is not creating a stacking context. It's just the propagation of the background to the canvas that's causing the effect you see.

Comment: @Alohci what you are saying is that the `html` tag **steals** (during rendering) the background color and image from the `body` tag, and now the `body` tag is rendered without background

Comment: You could put like that, yes. Once the html element has received the body's background, that background is then rendered by the canvas, not the html element. The fullest, latest description is to be found in [2.11. Backgrounds of Special Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds).

Comment: @Alohci I think there is a word missing in 2.11: "However, **when** the element whose background would be used for the canvas is display: none, ..." When I explicitly make the `body` tag a stacking context the render result is the same for the second example.

Comment: I agree about the missing word. I've added an answer to demonstrate that the body is not creating a stacking context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add a border to the body element, we can see that it is not in fact creating a stacking context. If the body element did create a stacking context, then the box would be painted over the border. But that doesn't happen: the border is painted over the box.

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:3px solid yellow;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: tomato;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
```

In contrast, if we force the body to create a stacking context - in the example below I've used `scale: 1` to do that - we can see that now the box is indeed painted over the body's border.

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:3px solid yellow;
  scale: 1;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: tomato;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
```

So we can be sure that the propagation of the body background to the canvas is not causing the body to create a stacking context - it's merely having a similar outcome when the body has no border.